# How to load an entire Visual c++ project into Enterprise Architect to reverse engineer it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enterprise-architect

Is there a way to load the DSW file for EA to then load the entire Visual C++ project?

Comment: I see a way to import C++ source files under Project->Source Code Engineering->C++ or C#, but nothing else.

Comment: I had done it before, but don't remember how?  I was able to load the whole project with all the wiring by clicking on a folder or dsw file.

Comment: I'm using EA 8.0.   Check that menu option that I cited above.

Comment: I can load the entire project:  Project->Source Code Engineering->Import Source Directory:(c++) & (path)

Comment: Thanks, gave pt.  Is there a simple way to arrange the spaghetti mess wiring... or only manually... it is a big legacy project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you can reverse engineer C++ code only from source code (header files) into EA.

There's also a VS AddIn available: [MDG Integration for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34896732-9677-4886-A0C1-CE530DBA65AA/), but that comes at extra cost.

The best way to get around the 'spaghetti mess wiring' is to draw diagrams for the classes of your interest manually. You can use the 'Add related elements' command from the (diagram) context menu of the classes you pick, this might be helpful.

Don't expect to get into programming against a complex legacy library API just from class diagrams without further documentation, but class diagrams can be helpful though to get a bird's view of the API structure.

Comment: +1 - I think this is the right answer.  I can't improve on it.

Comment: I can load the entire project: Project->Source Code Engineering->Import Source Directory:(c++) & (path)

and I can do Diagram->Layout Diagram to organize the wiring

Comment: @jdl An automatically created diagram from the imported classes will be layed out also by EA, but may be just not in the way you'd like to see.

Comment: @jdl You might try to print on either bigger paper size (e.g. A3) or export the diagram as image and resize this and fit to printing pages with a separate image manipulation program.